# compare two dictionary and update value in first dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have question on python dict update . I have two dict as mentioned below.

```
    dict1={1:{"partname": 'part1_item1' , 'archname':'sca_item1_rev1.0.jar','rev: '1.0', 'compname': item1},
           2:{"partname": 'part1_item2' , 'archname':'sca_item2_rev2.0.jar','rev: '2.0' ,'compname': item2},
           3:{"partname": 'part1_item3' , 'archname':'sca_item3_rev2.0.jar','rev: '2.0' ,'compname': item3}}
           
    dict2={item1:{'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname':'item1', 'partition': 'item1'},
           item2:{'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname':'item2', 'partition': 'item2'},
           item1:{'jarversion': '2.0', 'jarname':'item3', 'partition': 'item3'}}
```

I want to compare value (rev and jarname) dict1 with dict2  , if both jatname and jar version same then  i need to update in dict1 with 'overwrite': 'true'

if both version are not same and version not found then , i need to update with 'overwrite': 'false' in dict1

tried created code with dict1 as mentioned below

```
i=1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(comp):
    if files:
        if i not in dict1.keys():
            dict1[i] = {}
        if '\\' in root:
            subdir=root.split('\\')[1]
        else:
            subdir=''
        dict1[i].update({"partname" : '', "archname": '', "compname":'', "rev": ''})
        if subdir:
            dict1[i].update({"partname" : '%s'%subdir })
            dict1[i].update({"archname": '', "compname":'', "rev": ''})
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.jar'):
                dict1[i].update({"archname": '%s'%filename,"compname": ('%s' %filename).split('sca_')[1].split('_rev')[0],"rev": ('%s' %filename).split('sca_')[1].split('_rev')[1].split('.jar')[0]})
            else:
                print("Unrecognised file: %s"%(filename))
        i=i+1
```

dict2 already created.

i need to update my dict with below format.

```
if dict1(compname)(rev) == dict2 (jarversion)(jarname)
    
    dict1={1:{"partname": 'part1_item1' , 'archname':'sca_item1_rev1.0.jar','rev: '1.0', 'compname': item1 , 'overwrite' :'true'}}
    
if dict1(compname)(rev) != dict2 (jarversion)(jarname)
    
    dict1={1:{"partname": 'part1_item1' , 'archname':'sca_item1_rev1.0.jar','rev: '1.0', 'compname': item1 , 'overwrite' :'false'}}
```

Please help me how to update dict with this key:values.

Comment: You might need to fix ``dict2`` where key's are duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this,

```
# create a look-up set for unique (jarname + jarversion)
look_up = {v['jarname'] + v['jarversion'] for k, v in dict2.items()}

# use dict-comprehension for updating the values back to dict1
print(
    {k: {**v, **{"overwrite": v['compname'] + v['rev'] in look_up}}
     for k, v in dict1.items()}
)
```

**EDIT**, older version of python

```
look_up = set()

for _, v in dict2.items():
    look_up.add(v['jarname'] + v['jarversion'])

for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict1[k].update(
        {"overwrite": str(v['compname'] + v['rev'] in look_up).lower()}
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much . This is very useful code.. I guess there  is no duplicate value present on both dict.

Comment: Yeah sushant. I have replaced the correct value..But can you please tell me in my above where can I place this dict comprehensive..In the middle or at the last ..I have tried both but the doctor is not updating

Comment: The result of overwrite : True is showing i want to convert this one to 'true'.

Comment: I want to update the dict1 with this changes. How to update the dict1 using this

Comment: Sushant. I was tested this code on my laptop.which is having py 3.7 its working fine..But my test machine is having py 2.6.6. version .Hence this dict comprehension is showing invalid syntax is showing can you please help to convert this dict comprehension codes into 2.6.6..It would be really helpful to me

Comment: @sushanth...Please help me here

Comment: Thanks @sushanth ,  look_up = {v['jarname'] + v['jarversion'] for k, v in dict2.items()} ..can you please help me to convert in older version please

Comment: Sorry, you will need to open a new question for that.

Comment: I am new to Python ..I am trying to understanding the code. I am not sure about reposting the question to this forum..So can you please update the code here..Don't mind

Comment: ...I have opened a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62978295/convert-python-dict-comp-code-into-python-2-6-version

Comment: the new question post was deleted by admin. Can you please share code here

Comment: Thanks @sushanth ,  the env i am using python 2.2.1 in this set() is not working.look_up = set()  , is there anyway i can add it with the look_up dict

Comment: can you please help me here